# Can I use traCI to control traffic signal created by FLOW?

Tags: flow-project

I found the definition of network in SUMO is cumbersome, but FLOW makes it easier to define a larger network (e.g. 10*10 grid) in a more flexible way. I also hope vehicles can turn with certain probablities at intersections. Can I define such network and use traCI to control the generated traffic lights?

I have tried using traCI to control traffic lights of a small network generated by SUMO. We need to define routes for different type of vehicles, and I don't know how to expand the network and route vehicles with probability.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. Adding this capability is in progress and is tracked in this issue: https://github.com/flow-project/flow/issues/682

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since FLOW can control the traffic light with traCI in a RL experiment, can we directly call traCI in a non-RL simulation? If we can take advantage of FLOW to define the large grid network and set traffic flow, then can we call traCI to control the defined traffic lights?  Is there any conflict?

Comment: Basically I am asking, can we use FLOW to create the scenario/environment, and then use traCI to control the traffic lights we defined before? I think FLOW's convenience of defining network and vehicle flow should be combined with others.

Comment: I also would like to know how FLOW starts traCI when they apply RL rules to those traffic lights? Looks like traCI needs a network and route xml files in a specific format. I haven't seen such commands to generate those files for traCI. How does FLOW call traCI and use it to control traffic light?

Comment: Yes, you can directly call traCI in a non-RL experiment. I would take a look at the traffic light tutorial in the tutorials folder; it should (I hope!) answer most of these questions. We are actually directly using traCI to control the traffic lights as is; the network and node files are automatically generated by the Scenario classes. For more info on those there is a tutorial as well!

Comment: Hi Pao, we're migrating stackoverflow support to a Slack channel to make for easier responsiveness. Please join us at https://join.slack.com/t/flow-users/shared_invite/enQtNzk5NzE1OTkyNTE0LTU0YmE5ZTVkZmJmNDg1Nzg2YThjOThmY2ZlYWE2ZjQ0NTE1NjE3Y2YwMTljY2U5M2Y3MDhmMWUzZDM3YWViNmE!